# Add a column to a dataset whose values ​are filled by groups

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, which contains columns: week, shop, Item number and price. Also I have an array of unique numbers, which are equal to Item Numbers, but in different order.
I want to add new columns to this dataset based on these unique numbers. First of all, I need to group this dataset by week and shop. Then in particular week and particular shop I need to find an Item number which is equal to new column name (Element from array of unique numbers). If there is no such field fill with null.
Then i should fill all fields in a particular week and particular shop with price of this Item number.

Here some code that I've tried, but it works very slow, because the amount of rows is very big.

```py
#real dataset
data2
weeks = data2['Week'].unique()

for k in range(len(Unique_number)):
    for i in range(len(weeks)):
        temp_array = data2.loc[data2["Week"] == weeks[i]]
        stores = temp_array['Shop'].unique()
        for j in range(len(stores)):
            temp_array2 = temp_array.loc[data2["Shop"] == stores[j]]
            price = temp_array2.loc[temp_array2["Item number"] == Unique_number[k], "Price"]
            if (price.empty):
                price = 0 
            else:
                price = price.values[0]
            data2.loc[(data2["Week"] == weeks[i]) & (data2["Shop"] == stores[j]),Unique_number[k]] = price
```

I want something like this

```
Unique_numbers = [0,1,2,3]

dataframe before
week; shop; Item number; price
1     1     0            2
1     2     1            3
2     1     3            4
2     1     2            5
3     4     1            6
3     1     2            7



dataframe after
week; shop; Item number; price; 0; 1; 2; 3
1     1     0            2      2  0  0  0
1     2     1            3      0  3  0  0  
2     1     3            4      0  0  5  4
2     1     2            5      0  0  5  4
3     4     1            6      0  6  0  0
3     1     2            7      0  0  7  0
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don;t understand your output at all. What is the mapping of input values to output values? How do both `2 1 3 4` and `2 1 2 5` map to the same output, `0 0 5 4`?

Answer (score 2):

***Setup***

```
u = df['Item number'].to_numpy()
w = np.asarray(Unique_numbers)
g = [df.week, df.shop]
```

---

Using some broadcasted comparison here (assumes that all of your `price` values are greater than `0`).

---

```
pd.DataFrame(
  np.equal.outer(u, w) * df['price'].to_numpy()[:, None]).groupby(g).transform('max')
```

```
   0  1  2  3
0  2  0  0  0
1  0  3  0  0
2  0  0  5  4
3  0  0  5  4
4  0  6  0  0
5  0  0  7  0
```

Answer (score 1):

This turns out a combination of `pivot` and `merge`:

```
df.merge(df.pivot_table(index=['week', 'shop'], 
                       columns='Item number', 
                       values='price',
                       fill_value=0)
           .reindex(Unique_numbers, axis=1),
         left_on=['week', 'shop'],
         right_index=True,
         how='left'
        )
```

Output:

```
   week  shop  Item number  price  0  1  2  3
0     1     1            0      2  2  0  0  0
1     1     2            1      3  0  3  0  0
2     2     1            3      4  0  0  5  4
3     2     1            2      5  0  0  5  4
4     3     4            1      6  0  6  0  0
5     3     1            2      7  0  0  7  0
```

Comment: @user3483203 Thanks Chris, Updated my answer.